# Both www. and http:// websites are available 302

Tags: html, redirect

I am trying to optimize my website for Google, and now both www. and http:// give the same results indicating that Google is considering a duplicate content. I want only http://, and www. to be redirected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google can usually figure this stuff out for itself but if you need to give it a hint you can use Googles 'webmaster tools'. Also you should generally use 301 (Permanent) rather than 302 for this.

Comment: Google intentionally doesn't figure this (if you don't tell it, that is), as you might be using the www subdomain for some other intent.

Comment: Google Bot says - HTTP - 302 Found... I need to fix that. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, in your `.htaccess` or in an equivalent place:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```